# How to measure the compression with web audio api?

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api, meter

I would like to create a HTML meter to display the reduction made by the compressor node.

I used this code but it does not change the metter

```
compressor = context.createDynamicsCompressor();
compressor.threshold = -50;
compressor.ratio = 12;
compressor.attack = 0.003;
compressor.reduction.onchange = function () {
  var gainReduction = pluginSlot1.reduction;
  document.getElementById("meter").value = gainReduction.value;
};
```

This is connected to this HTML

> < meter id="meter" min="0" max="100">

What do I need to do in order for it to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty jsbin example: http://jsbin.com/ahocUt/1/edit

Unless there's something I'm missing in the spec, the `reduction` param doesn't fire any events. You just need to read it on-demand. In my example, that's just happening with a `requestAnimationFrame` loop.

The other thing you're missing is that you need to set the params with `compressor.threshold.value`, because `compressor.threshold` is actually an object.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've added something that was interesting for me, a way to change the color of the meter according to the compression level:

 
`if (( -1 * reduction ) < 10){ 
                bar.style.background =  "green";
            } else if (( -1 * reduction ) >= 10 && ( -1 * reduction ) < 20){
                bar.style.background =  "yellow";
            } else {
                bar.style.background =  "red";
            }`